# Compare and remove duplicates in Arrays (Google sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have two arrays of many rows , in my Google sheets, which have numbers such as

| Active | Recovered |
| --- | --- |
| 904;1505;1706 | 406;504;1502;1503 |
| **202**;401;602;1104;1501 | **202**;1502;1602;1704 |

I have shown only two rows to explain my problem. In the second row, you see that `202` is common. These rows are populated by complex calculations over which I have no control  <sup>1</sup>. Logically, if the element is common (`202` here), it should appear only under `Active` and be removed from `Recovered`.

How do I compare and remove the common element? Or at least alert me that a common element exists so that I can manually copy-paste that row and delete it?

<sup>1</sup> `Active` column is populated a formula like `=Join(";",Transpose(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER('2022'!D3:D319,TO_TEXT('2022'!F3:F319)="Active",'2022'!D3:D319<>"")),1,true),15,1)))`; similarly `Recovered` and I have no way of accessing the source. My job is to report the output and only today noticed the duplication

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this formula in row 2 of a free column:

`=arrayformula( iferror( substitute( trim( regexreplace( substitute(B2:B, ";", " "), "\b" & substitute(A2:A, ";", "\b|\b") & "\b", " " ) ), " ", ";" ) ) )`

The formula copies the contents of `B2:B` with the values in corresponding rows of `A2:A` removed separately in each row.

To learn the exact [regular expression](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754) syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

If you just want to flag rows with duplicates separately in each row of `A2:B`, you can get a row-by-row count like this:

`=arrayformula( iferror( 1 / sum( iferror( match( split(A2, ";"), split(B2, ";"), 0 ) ) ) ^ -1 ) )`

The formula will give a blank on rows where there are no duplicates, and the number of duplicates on rows where there are duplicates.